# How to force VueJS custom component to re-render itself and all its child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a use case where I have a custom Vue Component that populates its child components dynamically using the JSON. When this top level vue component is created it loads all the children components using the JSON. I have a provision where I can add additional controls on the form when I update the JSON from which it renders itself.

So when I update the JSON on backend using AJAX, I would like re-render everything upon successful post.

Also I came across few articles that say that the regenerating the Form on Custom Vue component should be handled using v-show and/or v-if directive.
This will not fit with my use case.

I looked into  [forceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) API, which is applicable for current component only. It does not affect child components.

So looks like handling forceUpdate on every component is the only way to go in my use case?

[image]

Based on the diagram you can see that in the MainFrom component is top level component. Following is the template for the MainForm:

```
<template>
 <div>
    <div v-for="(entity, index) of mySchemaChunks >
         <FormSection :componentList="entity" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
   store,

   computed: {
      mySchemaChunks() {
         // returns the chunks from schema (schema is stored in Vuex) 
         // where each chunks is array (segments of schema)
         // Each chunk is a section that has its own list of 
         // controls. 
      }
   },

   methods: {
       addNewJsonSchemaNodes() {
         // This function will update master Json schema in the backend
         // using AJAX which was used to generate the JSON from which
         // we generate the MainFrom and all its children
         // When App is initialized it prepares the JSON to generate
         // MainForm and store that JSON in the Vuex module as schema 
         // and model object

         // I do an AJAX post here which only send me status 200
         // This is not enough for me to re-render and generate all
         // dynamic component

         // May be I should try to get back the JSON after successful
         // update of Master JSON in backend ... so that I can update 
         // my Vuex module schema and model object with new values ...
         // And that should do the trick and all components (parent to 
         // children will be rendered ...????

         // Edit: OK.. Now I am getting the data back from AJAX post 
         // which is now rendering the entire form
       }

   }
}
</script>
```

Here is the high level overview of section

```
<template>
<div>
   // Render the list of entity passed to it as property in v-for 
   // This will add the dynamic Vue components as its children
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please provide a simplified [mcve] of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Vue is data-driven, that means if the json data change, the child component bind some properties of the json data, it will be updated also. can you share your MCV codes?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're not using Vue.js correctly. Except in unusual cases (e.g. storing your data in a `Set`), Vue.js should update parent and child components automatically.

Comment: I have fixed this by firing the custom event which all components handles (except parent component) to destroy itself. Then I reset my variables to new data and parents then re-render the entire form. However I am wondering if I have to even destroy all child components or not. Because my current way of destroying all children and changing the data to re-render the UI is causing a side effect where it seems the destroyed components appears to be still cached by vue and they are acting on custom event and corrupting some data in my model in Vuex store.

Comment: Probably setting correct keys will fix it ? Not sure ... but definitely weird caching (not sure if this is caching issue .. but most probably) or component key issue. Because it appears that $destroy function does not remove the components from cache ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forceUpdate()` won't rerender children component UI, but tracked properties will.

In your case. You need to bind the data to component at first. Once ajax response back, you just call `Vue.set` to update the data bound and it will automatically update the children components

Comment: Yes. This is what I did. And it work. There is no need to explicitly destroy any children.