# Does $destroy function removes the Vue Custom component from cache

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I construct deep nested tree of parent and children Vue custom components using my top level component dynamically and then I am updating the data from which all tree is constructed. Which has an effect of rendering the entire tree (its a form with various custom components). I refresh/rebuild the whole form after fetching the data (which is what vue do for reactive data) that itself tell me how to regenerate the view (its like a JSON Schema from which I render the entire view).

This is related to my other issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069608/how-to-force-vuejs-custom-component-to-re-render-itself-and-all-its-child-compon).

I am observing a very weird behavior in my Vue Application. When I destroy all my children components and rebuild the data to force rendering the form, it appears that even after I have called $destroy on every child component...Vue is not entirely removing them from cache?

**Does vue remove the component from cache if a $destroy is called ?**

Because I do not see multiple components of the same type in the Vue component list in the Chrome Vue DevTool extension panel. But I see that the same custom event is handled twice by the same component. Same function that handle the events is getting called twice even though there is only one component visible in Vue DevTools of this type.

This only happens after I render the form. When the page is loaded for the first time every thing works. Then after I reset the form by destroying the child component and resetting the data to re-render the form, magically this child component start handling the event twice.. and in 3rd render it handle the events thrice. But I see only one component in google chrome VueJS DevTool extension panel. So my guess is that vue is still keeping the previously destroyed component in cache. I am trying to figure out how should I destroy those components in the cache.

**If anyone has observed something similar and found a solution please let me know.**

At the moment I am going to dig little bit more on my component keys (this particular component does not have explicit key set by me).

Comment: If you could add a code example, I can customize my general answer to it

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, the vue documentation states:

[`vm.$destroy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy)

> **In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself.**
> Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven
> fashion using v-if and v-for.

So instead of destroying and rebuilding the components manually yourself, you should really letting vue handle that via `v-if` and `v-for`. If the components aren't updating to your changes, you might be dealing with a [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) issue.

As you mentioned that this is a deeply nested structure, the reactivity is key to keeping the components up to data with the data.

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` method:

```
Vue.set(vm.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

Inside of a component:

```
this.$set(this.someObject, 'b', 2)
```

Also, keep in mind that `Vue` should be doing the heavy lifting in regards to component management, while you should define the parameters by which a component is rendered.